# How can I prove that $|\langle w,v\rangle| \leq 1$?

Tags: linear-algebra

How can I go about proving that if $\|w\| = \|v\| = 1$, then $|\langle w, v\rangle| \leq 1$?

I know that $\langle w,v\rangle = w_1v_1 + w_2v_2 + \cdots $ but I am not sure how to use that to prove this.

Comment: cauchy schwarz inequality

Answer (score 4):

Hint: Recall the [Cauchy-Schwarz Inequality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Schwarz_inequality).

$$|\langle x,y\rangle| ^2 \leq \langle x,x\rangle \cdot \langle y,y\rangle,$$

$$|\langle x,y\rangle| \leq \|x\| \cdot \|y\|.$$

You can explore its various applications and extensions at the Wikipedia Entry linked above.

Comment: $\ddot\smile$ for my friend.

Comment: $\quad \ddot\smile\quad$ Good morning, Babak, dear friend!

Answer (score 1):

Remember the *definition* of cosine in an inner product linear space: if the angle between two vectors $\,u,v\,$ is $\,\theta\,$ , then

$$\cos\theta:=\frac{\langle\,u,\, v\,\rangle}{||u||\,||v||}$$

Now just remember that $\,|\cos\theta|\le 1\,$ ...(This follows from Cauchy-Schwarz).

If you defined the inner product by means of the above equation then trigonometry came first and you also know that $\,|\cos\theta|\le 1\,$, so either way...